# Turn screen off but keep all-in-one PC running

Tags: windows-10, display

Is there a way for me to turn off the 'monitor' of my all-in-one Windows 10 PC (so that the screen is blank) but have the PC continue running such that typing, mouse clicks etc will still work? Like on a computer with a separate monitor you could turn it off and continue typing.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have an option under power settings.  `Turn-off Screen` after so many minutes.  Just make it ie 5min, and increase `Stand by` to longer or disable it.  You have to be careful as some AiO, can't wake up screen if it gets turn-off, so you will end up rebooting computer. [image: Change settings for the plan:]

Comment: This doesn't do what I need, though, because as soon as I click the mouse or type a key, the screen comes back on again. I basically want to replicate what happens on a 'normal' computer where you can simply switch off (or unplug) the monitor and everything else carries on as normal.

Comment: you can choose which events will wake up screen ie. remove mouse from being able to wake it up.  Obviously there is no physical switch on AiO, so it has to be done via Software, and this is how you can do it in Windows, unless you want to create/find software to do just that.

Comment: How can I choose which events will wake up screen?